# Connection Fails for Win 8 64 bit ACCESS 32 bit, Access Database Engine

Tags: ms-access, database-connection

Environment: Win8 64 bit, Office 2010 32 bit.  Using tips seen here, I installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe as passive (so that it could be installed with 32 bit Office), and had no connection problems with Access .mdb files  until two days ago.  Now the connection fails on all .mdb files, with C# debugger showing "unknown error" with "external component".  Connection string uses ACE 12.0.  I changed nothing in code, which was compiled for 64bit.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe as passive again?

Comment: Yes. No errors on reinstall. Although, the registry path egistry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\FilesPaths did not contain a key or value for "mso.dll" which I thought odd since I had previously deleted it so that ACE would work with the 32 bit Access.  I tried deleting the keys in FilesPaths and reinstalling again, and no keys were replaced.  Has there been some change in the installation of the AccessDatabaseEngine so that theregistry no longer uses FilesPaths? Thanks for the suggestion though, I am grateful for any help.